# datatables - how to get the first column value

Tags: datatables

I have a delete button at the end of each row

First column in the table is hidden (server row id) ,

How to I get to the first column value given the TR object?

```js
$('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_remove', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var oTableApi = $('#example').dataTable().api();
     var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
     alert(tr.first('td').text()); // return all the columns as one text.
});
```

Comment: what version of datatables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dare to answer as you were using datatables < v1.10.x. It works with 1.10.x also, but then I would recommend another approach. It is actually far more easy than you think.

If you have rows like this :

```html
<tr>
    <td>1</td> <!-- server row id -->
    <td>content #1</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="delete" value="delete"/></td>
</tr>
```

and initialised a datatable :

```js
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({});
```

and have hidden the first column :

```js
dataTable.fnSetColumnVis(0, false);
```

then, all you have to do to get the value of the first column, when clicking on the buttons is :

```js
$('.delete').click(function(e) {
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr');    
   //get the real row index, even if the table is sorted 
   var index = dataTable.fnGetPosition(tr[0]);
   //alert the content of the hidden first column 
   alert(dataTable.fnGetData(index)[0]);
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/avPSL/**

Comment: it works only first page in Laravel blade
on pagination onward 2nd page its dose not work

Comment: @AdnanZaheer, use a delegated event handler `$('#example').on('click', '.delete', function(e) { ... }) `...

Answer (score 1):

davidkonrad solution is working great, 
I found this jquery td:first trick to work as well, so just in case:

```
        var oTableApi = $('#example').dataTable().api();
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        td = tr.find("td:first")
        var cell = oTableApi.cell(td);
        alert(cell.data());
```

Comment: So you _are_ using 1.10.x :) **NOTE** : `td:first` will only work if you have hidden the column by `display:none`; if the column is hidden the traditional datatables way with `fnSetColumnVis` or similar, `td:first` will return column #2, since `fnSetColumnVis` removes the entire column from the DOM. See example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/TwHA5/**.